# What factors of the integer dataset being sorted can I change, in order to compare two sorting algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, binary-search-trees, data-sets, heap-sort

I am comparing two comparison and binary data structure based sorting algorithms, the Tree Sort, and the Heap Sort. I am measuring the time taken for both algorithms to sort an increasing size of an integer dataset. However, I am wondering if there are any other variables which I can modify, for example standard deviation, in the integer dataset itself that would be of any benefit to my comparison.

Comment: Range, and, related, multiplicity of item values.

Answer (score 1):

Try these: Sorted. Reverse sorted. Two sorted halves. One half ascending, one half descending. Sorted with 0.1%, 1%, 10% random changes. Random. All values equal, 99% equal, 50% equal. Two different values only.

Unless you are 100% sure that one of these case cannot happen (and you are never 100% sure), all of these should run in a reasonable time. Some of them, like "Sorted" or "sorted with 0.1% random changes" can run much faster than others. If these cases are common, then you would want them to run faster.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is not doing a proper shuffle, that is having partially (reverse) sorted sequences, in extremis this can be the entire range is sorted except a few elements at the end that need to be inserted somewhere in the range.

For comparison sorts the distribution of elements doesn't make a difference, only how many duplicate values there are. This is something you can adjust as well.